# How to echo the query result 1 by 1?

Tags: php, mysql

My query is :

```
$qStuff=mysql_query("SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_id = t.category_id AND t.domain_id = d.domain_id AND c.field_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($first_word) . "'");
```

How to echo the c.field_name ,t.category_name and d.domain_name separately ?

Output like this

Field name :

Category name :

Domain name :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qStuff)) {

    echo 'Field name: ' . $row['c.field_name'] . '<br />'; 
    echo 'Category name: ' . $row['t.category_name'] . '<br />'; 
    echo 'Domain name: ' . $row['d.domain_name'] . '<br />'; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $qStuff=mysql_query("SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_id = t.category_id AND t.domain_id = d.domain_id AND c.field_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($first_word) . "'");


 $result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($qStuff);
 echo "Field name: ", $result_array["field_name"], "<br />";
 echo "Category name: ", $result_array["category_name"], "<br />";
 echo "Domain name: ", $result_array["domain_name"], "<br />";
 echo "<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$qStuff = mysql_query("SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_id = t.category_id AND t.domain_id = d.domain_id AND c.field_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($first_word) . "'");

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($qStuff) ){

     echo "Field Name: " . $row['c.field_name'] . "<br />";
     echo "Category Name: ". $row['t.category_name'] . "<br />";
     echo "Domain Name: " . $row['d.domain_name'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```